# How to show this content without press the button?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, jsoup

I would like to show direct this content without press the buttons. Can someone help me? I'm new to the programming world.

In the below have the complete content, if you want to analyze better.

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

```js
 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 // URL Address
 String url = "http://www.androidbegin.com";
 ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
 
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
  // Locate the Buttons in activity_main.xml
  Button titlebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.titlebutton);
       
  // Capture button click
  titlebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // Execute Title AsyncTask
    new Title().execute();
   }
  });
 
 }
 
 // Title AsyncTask
 private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  String title;
 
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
   
  }
 
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   try {
    // Connect to the web site
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    // Get the html document title
    title = document.title();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  }
 
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   // Set title into TextView
   TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
   txttitle.setText(title);
   mProgressDialog.dismiss();
  }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put following code directly under the line  `setContentView...`

```
new Title().execute();
```

Comment: its works bro.. thx ... and to execute multiple AsynTaks in the same time like the tutorial? http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, please accept it as the solution. AsyncTask are executed asynchronously. If you want to call multiple AsyncTask at the same time just add another line e.g. "new Description().execute();" after your new Title()...

Comment: its because I trying it bro.. but, the ProgressDialog never stop to load